# Couchbase Sync-Gateway View Index Failure

Tags: rest, couchbase, couchbase-view, couchbase-sync-gateway

I'm using Couchbase to power the back end of my mobile app and am experiencing a strange error when using `views`.

I have a view set up to fetch a specific document type and am querying that view via the Sync-Gateway [admin API](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/references/sync-gateway/admin-rest-api/index.html#/query/get__db___design__ddoc___view__view_). Normally it works well but I've found that if a document has been recently added to the database then the view query will return 0 results on the first request. The second *identical* request will then return the expected response.

I suspect that the new document hasn't been indexed by couchbase yet and the query triggers a re-indexing of documents. What I'm wondering is if there's a way of notifying couchbase that I'm about to query the view and to prepare the documents in advance. I don't want to have to perform 2 requests for each query.

Has anyone else come across this issue?

Any solutions?

Comment: What versions of Sync Gateway and Couchbase Server are you running? How are you creating the new document?

Comment: Sync-Gateway is 1.5.1-community. Couchbase Server is latest so 5.1. New document is created from a custom API that uses the admin API over port 4985

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Sync Gateway allows using a "stale" index, meaning a query won't necessarily rebuild the index before processing a query.

To override this, add `stale=false` to your query.

(Allowed options are `false`, `ok`, and `update_after`. The default is `update_after`.)